# How to group dictionary keys based on their list values matching condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, collections

I would like to group the keys of dictionary based on the list value assigned to the key. For example,

```
edge_dict = {'ED7':[[15,-10,0], [20,-10,0]], 'ED10':[[0,0,0],[10,0,0]], 'ED13':[[15,0,0], [20,0,0]], 'ED4':[[20,0,0], [25,0,0]], 'ED2':[[15,0,0], [10,0,0]], 'ED5':[[0,-10,0],[10,-10,0]], 'ED6':[[15,-10,0], [10,-10,0]], 'ED8':[[20,-10,0], [25,-10,0]]}

rib1_edges  :  ['ED10', 'ED5']

rib2_edges  :  ['ED4', 'ED8']
```

Dictionary "edge_dict " have a Key 'ED10' whose sub list ([10,0,0]) is equal to another key in the same dictionary, that is, 'ED2'. Likewise, i would like to collect and group all those keys in edge_dict which are connected by a common sublist value.

Expected answer is

```
selected_group_1 = {'ED10':[[0,0,0],[10,0,0]], 'ED2':[[15,0,0], [10,0,0]], 'ED13':[[15,0,0], [20,0,0]], 'ED4':[[20,0,0], [25,0,0]]}
selected_group_2 = {'ED5':[[0,-10,0],[10,-10,0]], 'ED6':[[15,-10,0], [10,-10,0]], 'ED7':[[15,-10,0], [20,-10,0]], 'ED8':[[20,-10,0], [25,-10,0]]}
```

It should be noted that the selected groups have an order from values in list  rib1_edges to rib2_edges. That means one group starts with key 'ED10' and ends in either 'ED4' or 'ED8' depending on how values are arranged in edge_dict.

Can anyone help me to group the dictionary "edge_dict" as shown in the expected answer?

I started off something like this,

```
import math

def is_equal(pnt1, pnt2):
    L = math.sqrt((pnt1[0]-pnt2[0]) ** 2 + (pnt1[1]-pnt2[1]) ** 2 + (pnt1[2]-pnt2[2]) ** 2)
    if L<1e-4:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(len(list(edge_dict.keys()))/2):
    for ed, pnts in {k:v for k, v in edge_dict.items() if k not in list(selected_group_1.keys())}.items():
        if (any(is_equal(selected_group_1[edge][0], pnts[0]) or any(is_equal(selected_group_1[edge][1], pnts[0]) or any(is_equal(selected_group_1[edge][0], pnts[1]) or any(is_equal(selected_group_1[edge][1], pnts[1])):
            selected_group_1[ed] = pnts
```

I could not put the logic properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically asking for an algorithm that can calculate connected components in a graph. Although you could write it by hand using either DFS or BFS, sometimes it's more convenient to use a ready-made solution such as [scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components) .

You have to transform your graph in a way that can be digested by the algorithm.

## Invert keys and values

Invert keys and values and build the dictionary `dct`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

edge_dict = {
    'ED7':[[15,-10,0], [20,-10,0]],
    'ED10':[[0,0,0],[10,0,0]],
    'ED13':[[15,0,0], [20,0,0]],
    'ED4':[[20,0,0], [25,0,0]],
    'ED2':[[15,0,0], [10,0,0]],
    'ED5':[[0,-10,0],[10,-10,0]],
    'ED6':[[15,-10,0], [10,-10,0]],
    'ED8':[[20,-10,0], [25,-10,0]]
}

edge_pairs = [ ['ED10', 'ED5'], ['ED4', 'ED8'] ]

dct = defaultdict(list)

for item in edge_dict.items():
    key = item[0]
    value = item[1]
    for lst in value:
        hashed_lst = str(lst)
        dct[hashed_lst].append(key)

print(dct)
```

This will be the output of `dct`.

```
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'[15, -10, 0]': ['ED7', 'ED6'],
# '[20, -10, 0]': ['ED7', 'ED8'],
# '[0, 0, 0]': ['ED10'],
# '[10, 0, 0]': ['ED10', 'ED2'],
# '[15, 0, 0]': ['ED13', 'ED2'],
# '[20, 0, 0]': ['ED13', 'ED4'],
# '[25, 0, 0]': ['ED4'],
# '[0, -10, 0]': ['ED5'],
# '[10, -10, 0]': ['ED5', 'ED6'],
# '[25, -10, 0]': ['ED8']})
```

## Adjacency List

- Build an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) of your ED labels and call it `graph_dct`. If there's an edge between two labels, then they belong to the same group.

  graph_dct = defaultdict(list)

  for lst in dct.values():
      for item in lst:
          for item2 in lst:
              if item != item2:
                  graph_dct[item].append(item2)

  print(graph_dct)

This will be the output of `graph_dct`.

```
    # graph_dct :
    # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ED7': ['ED6', 'ED8'],
    # 'ED6': ['ED7', 'ED5'],
    # 'ED8': ['ED7'], 'ED10': ['ED2'],
    # 'ED2': ['ED10', 'ED13']
    # 'ED13': ['ED2', 'ED4'],
    # 'ED4': ['ED13'], 'ED5': ['ED6']})
```

## Adjacency Matrix

This is a requirement of the scipy connected components algorithm. We must transform our adjacency list into an [adjacency matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html). It will be called `sparse_matrix`.

```
graph_dct_keys = list(graph_dct.keys());

sparse_matrix = []
for key in graph_dct_keys:
    row = [0] * len(graph_dct_keys)
    for item in graph_dct[key]:
        row[graph_dct_keys.index(item)] = 1
    sparse_matrix.append(row)
```

## Algorithm

Now we pass `sparse_matrix` to the connected components algorithm and then it will give you the groups.

```
components = csr_matrix(sparse_matrix)
n_components, labels = connected_components(csgraph=components, directed=False, return_labels=True)

labels_dct = defaultdict(list)

for idx, item in enumerate(labels):
    labels_dct[str(item)].append(graph_dct_keys[idx])

print(labels_dct.values())
# dict_values([
# ['ED7', 'ED6', 'ED8', 'ED5'],
# ['ED10', 'ED2', 'ED13', 'ED4']
# ])

results = list(labels_dct.values())
```

Now you have `results`, which is a list of lists of labels that can be used to build your expected answer very easily.

## Sorting

Next we'll sort `results` according to the requirements and generate the expected answer.

```
results = [['ED7', 'ED6', 'ED8', 'ED5'], ['ED10', 'ED2', 'ED13', 'ED4']]
rib1_edges = ['ED10', 'ED5']
rib2_edges = ['ED4', 'ED8']
for idx,lst in enumerate(results):
    results[idx] = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.lstrip('ED')) )
for idx,lst in enumerate(results):
    results[idx] = [ x for x in rib1_edges if x in lst ] + \
        [ x for x in lst if x not in rib1_edges and x not in rib2_edges ] + \
        [ x for x in rib2_edges if x in lst ]

print(results)
```

This will give the desired result, 
`[['ED5', 'ED6', 'ED7', 'ED8'], ['ED10', 'ED2', 'ED13', 'ED4']]` .

## Getting the Answer

Notice that there's no guarantee that this dictionary will be insertion ordered if you're using a version of Python below 3.6 . In that case, the keys may appear in any seemingly random order determined by Python's internal algorithm.

So if you're running Python 3.6+ it's ok to use a dictionary, but for portability, it's better to go with an OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

edge_dict = {
    'ED7':[[15,-10,0], [20,-10,0]],
    'ED10':[[0,0,0],[10,0,0]],
    'ED13':[[15,0,0], [20,0,0]],
    'ED4':[[20,0,0], [25,0,0]],
    'ED2':[[15,0,0], [10,0,0]],
    'ED5':[[0,-10,0],[10,-10,0]],
    'ED6':[[15,-10,0], [10,-10,0]],
    'ED8':[[20,-10,0], [25,-10,0]]
}

result = [
          ['ED5', 'ED6', 'ED7', 'ED8'],
          ['ED10', 'ED2', 'ED13', 'ED4']
]

answer = []
for lst in result:
    od = OrderedDict()
    for item in lst:
        od[item] = edge_dict[item]
    answer.append(od)

import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(answer)
```

And then this will give us the expected answer.

```
[OrderedDict([('ED5', [[0, -10, 0], [10, -10, 0]]),
              ('ED6', [[15, -10, 0], [10, -10, 0]]),
              ('ED7', [[15, -10, 0], [20, -10, 0]]),
              ('ED8', [[20, -10, 0], [25, -10, 0]])]),
 OrderedDict([('ED10', [[0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0]]),
              ('ED2', [[15, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0]]),
              ('ED13', [[15, 0, 0], [20, 0, 0]]),
              ('ED4', [[20, 0, 0], [25, 0, 0]])])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Ruan. I would like the result list to be in the same order as the expected answer shown above. That is, [ ['ED10', 'ED2', 'ED13', 'ED4'] ['ED5', 'ED6', 'ED7', 'ED8']]. This order is based on the list rib1_edges and rib2_edges. In the result list, first sub list should start with 'ED10' (rib1_edges[0]) and end in one of the value in rib2_edges. Similarly, Second sub list should start from 'ED5' (rib1_edges[1]) and end one of the value in rib2_edges. Can you suggest a way to do this also?